# Export postgres table to csv error

Tags: database, postgresql, export-to-csv

I am trying to export all my tables of postrgres into individual csv files for that I am using  the following function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION db_to_csv(path text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
  tables RECORD;
  statement TEXT;
begin
  FOR tables IN 
    SELECT (table_schema || '.' || table_name) AS schema_table
    FROM information_schema.tables t INNER JOIN information_schema.schemata s 
    ON s.schema_name = t.table_schema 
    WHERE t.table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema', 'configuration')
    ORDER BY schema_table
  LOOP
    statement := 'COPY ' || tables.schema_table || ' TO ''' || path || '/' || tables.schema_table || '.csv' ||''' DELIMITER '';'' CSV HEADER';
    EXECUTE statement;
  END LOOP;
  return;  
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION db_to_csv(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

but when I am calling this function I am getting could not open file "/home/user/Documents/public.tablename.csv" for writing: Permission denied

I have tried copying individual table using

```
COPY activities TO '/home/user/Documents/foldername/conversions/tablename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

It gives me the following error

```
ERROR:  could not open file "/home/user/Documents/foldername/conversions/tablename.csv" for writing: Permission denied


********** Error **********

 ERROR:  could not open file "/home/user/Documents/foldername/conversions/tablename.csv" for writing: Permission denied
SQL state: 42501
```

Any suggestions how to fix this.

Comment: *COPY will be run by the PostgreSQL backend (user "postgres").* That user needs to be able to write that file.  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY

Comment: I have tried that under console only. Was giving me permission denied error. Changed the ownership to 777 now working fine J.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a folder on which every user has access. Then run the COPY command on a file there. COPY works only on directories where postgres user has access

```
sudo mkdir /media/export
sudo chmod 777 /media/export

COPY activities TO '/media/export/activities.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: this did not work fro me. 
however this worked -> https://www.masterywithdata.com/blog/copy-permission-denied/

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and I followed the second answer

> Make a folder on which every user has access. Then run the COPY command on a file there. COPY works only on directories where postgres user has access

This didn't work for me.

So, I performed copy to /tmp/somename.csv and then copied the file to my actual required location for usage.

```
\copy query TO '/tmp/somename.csv' with csv;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not working after given permission.

Now I tried to export the same location where greenplum data available i.e  greenplum/data, now permission denied problem get resolved.

COPY Table_Name TO '/home/greenplum/data/table_data_export.csv';